# Fragment Shader Calculating If a Coordinate Is Within a Given Set of Points

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0

I was wondering how would you calculate if the given coordinate for a fragment shader falls within a specified square.  Is there some function for that?

Comment: What coordinates? screen position? Are you thinking of a clipping rectangle? We need more information

Comment: Correct.  Basically a clipping rectangle.  I am trying to only apply a specific color to a specific rectangle on the screen.  All other pixels remain the same.

Comment: Please forgive me if I am not asking the right question.  I am extremely new to OpenGL.

Comment: I also wanted to add.. I think the approach is to calculate the area of the four triangles given the texture coordinate in the fragment shader.  If all four of those areas == the area of the two triangles that make up the square, then it's good to go.  I've read IF statements are fairly expensive.

Comment: you can set up a clipping rectangle using scissor. use glScissor to setup the rectangle, on glEnable/Disable( GL_SCISSOR ) to activate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GL_SCISSOR did the trick! Thanks for the help!